# Failed to download repository information (related topics did not seem to answer my question)

Tags: 12.04, repository

```
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/dists/pangolin/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.190 80]
, W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/dists/pangolin/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.190 80]
, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

[image]

I am running 12.04 x86, but when I check the sources.list file, there is nothing in there that seems to reference anything i386 (but the error spits out 'i386' as part of the repo url). I think it has to do with my above setup, because I am choosing to run the latest software? I'm just not sure where to look to resolve this. sources.list isn't helping :(

Comment: These sources might be bad. Just remove these lines from your sources.list and it should be fine.

Comment: @Mitch I don't see anything referencing 'i386' in my sources.list, that's the problem (as I already mentioned above). What should I remove?

Answer (score -1):

The error you are getting is 404 HTML not Found.
In order to solve this.

Try using a different Mirror:

- Click on Download From.
- Click on Download From.
- Then Choose Other Location
- Then choose Choose Best Server
- it will scan and find the best servers closest to you.

[image]

[image]

If you want to do this manually you will need to look in:

> ```
> /etc/apt/sources.list
>  /etc/apt/sources.list.d
> ```

in **sources.list.d** there are individual files for each of the sets of external sources. Instead of everything in one sources.list file.

you could do a grep to find the offending line in /etc/apt:

```
grep -Hrin "http://archive.ubuntu.com/dists/pangolin/main/binary-i386/Packages" /etc/apt

grep -Hrin "http://archive.ubuntu.com/dists/pangolin/universe/binary-i386/Packages" /etc/apt
```